# Where can i set the location of the css file in wordPress using php?

Tags: php, wordpress, stylesheet

I am using wordpress and am trying to link to the stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

It is not recognizing that link tag, because I think the bloginfo('stylesheet_url') part is not working correctly.

Where can I set the location of the stylesheet url in wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what should be specified:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" />
```

You are specifying correctly, make sure that you have put the CSS file in the root of your **theme** folder and the CSS file is named **style.css**

Comment: I did and I named it style.css. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: @zeckdude: That is weird, the only difference is that i have not specified `media="screen"`.

Comment: Where is the name of the css file specified or does it always have to be named style.css?

Comment: Also make sure that  you have `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in the header.php file and `<?php get_header(); ?>` in index.php file or other files.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for those who want their stylesheet inside a subdirectory such as /css is to use `bloginfo('template_url')` instead of `bloginfo('stylesheet_url')`

Append the directory and stylesheet name inside the link href and outside the PHP tags

e.g.:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/style.css" 
media="screen" />
```

`If (OOPS=='where did my background images go') {` add relative path to image references in style sheet i.e. `url(images/mybackground.jpg)` becomes `url(../images/mybackground.jpg)` `}`